# Summoned custom Armor Stand creation with command block, can't remove it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm a little late to discover the mrgarretto armor stand generator. I was attempting to make or find some furniture for my house. Found a couch I liked the look of and decided to place it in my world to see how it looked. Didn't stop to consider that I am a total newb when it comes to this sort of thing and can't figure out how to remove it. To clarify, the destroy command does not work:

```
execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=AM_VRXpaX_M] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[tag=AM_VRXpaX,c=34]
```

Here is the ridiculously long command for the couch itself, if that's helpful:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~1.0 ~ {Block:stone,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:activator_rail,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"gamerule commandBlockOutput false"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"scoreboard teams add noColAM_VRXpaX"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"scoreboard teams option noColAM_VRXpaX collisionRule never"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.40625 ~-3.10793 ~0.28125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.40625 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.65625 ~-3.10793 ~0.28125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.0 ~-3.73293 ~0.0 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.5625 ~-4.44133 ~0.1875 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.9375 ~-4.44133 ~0.1875 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.3125 ~-4.44133 ~0.1875 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.3125 ~-4.44133 ~0.1875 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.65625 ~-3.10793 ~-0.15625 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.34375 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.40625 ~-4.44133 ~-0.375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.65625 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.21875 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.78125 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.34375 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.09375 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.40625 ~-2.67043 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.875 ~-4.44133 ~-0.34375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.21875 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.78125 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.0 ~-3.60793 ~0.0 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.0 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.125 ~-4.44133 ~-0.4375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.3125 ~-4.44133 ~-0.4375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-0.71875 ~-4.44133 ~-0.4375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.5625 ~-4.44133 ~-0.4375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1.65625 ~-3.10793 ~-0.53125 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~-1 ~-4.44133 ~-0.4375 {DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon villager ~-1.40625 ~-2.86832 ~-0.0625 {Age:-1000000,NoGravity:1,Team:noColAM_VRXpaX,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:9999999,ShowParticles:false}],Rotation:[45f,0f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:wool,Damage:9,Count:1}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon villager ~-1.21875 ~-2.86832 ~-0.25 {Age:-1000000,NoGravity:1,Team:noColAM_VRXpaX,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:9999999,ShowParticles:false}],Rotation:[45f,0f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:wool,Damage:9,Count:1}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon villager ~-1.40625 ~-3.14957 ~-0.0625 {Age:-1000000,NoGravity:1,Team:noColAM_VRXpaX,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:9999999,ShowParticles:false}],Rotation:[45f,0f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:wool,Damage:9,Count:1}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon villager ~-1.21875 ~-3.14957 ~-0.25 {Age:-1000000,NoGravity:1,Team:noColAM_VRXpaX,Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:9999999,ShowParticles:false}],Rotation:[45f,0f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:wool,Damage:9,Count:1}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"summon armor_stand ~0.40625 ~-3.10793 ~-0.09375 {Small:1,DisabledSlots:4096,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:wool}]}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~ ~ ~1.0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"fill ~ ~-3 ~-1 ~ ~ ~ air\"}"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"setblock ~ ~-1 ~1.0 redstone_block"},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:"kill @e[type=commandblock_minecart,r=1]"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Why can't you just use `kill @e[type=armor_stand,r=3]` while standing near it?

Answer (score 1):

Your command summons armor stands and villagers.

Go stand next to the couch and run these two commands:

```
/kill @e[type=armor_stand,r=5]
/kill @e[type=villager,r=5]
```

Be careful if any villagers or armor stands that you care about are in the same area.  If need be, you can reduce the [radius](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_radius) within the commands.

You may also want these commands to undo other things that command did:

```
/scoreboard teams remove noColAM_VRXpaX
/gamerule commandBlockOutput true
```

This has been tested:
[image: No More Couch]

One last thing, a suggestion.  Make a new world to test things like your command.  This way you can delete it if you really mess something up.  It removes the risk of damaging a world you play and care about.

Comment: THANK YOU for that, it worked! Pretty ridiculous that I should have to ask, but I just couldn't figure this one out. Thank you again for taking the time to test it out yourself and respond!